# Bring element to front using css on wordpress page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hello i am working on a wordpress page

i am trying to bring my logo to the front of a top bar, which is shown here

```
http://polocalendar.com/2018/01/27/magazine/
```

on that page the logo hides behind the top bar in white background

i am trying to bring this to the front of the white bar

below is what i am trying, i have applied  position relative and index -1 but it still hides, please help

```
.navbar .navbar-brand img {
    position: relative!important;
    z-index: -1!important;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    height: 120px;
    max-height: 120px;
    max-width: 300px;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}
```

Comment: Your logo looks fine to me, can you elaborate on what the desired result is? (like which element should be in the front etc)

Comment: `z-index: -1` wil make it go further in the background. Make the number higher.

Comment: Same, your logo is there on my screen. But instead of setting the logo to -1, try setting it to 9999 !

Comment: i want the logo to come to the front, presently the logo is under the white background, see wat am trying to achieve here, http://polocalendar.com/  this page is made up of rows

Comment: guys i am trying to achieve this http://polocalendar.com/

Comment: **Read the comments**.  @ThomasvanOorschot gave you an answer above.  TRY IT, and report back here.

Comment: yea, read the comments but, wat i meant was that my logo was partially covered and fully covered and thats why i pasted this link where i built the page with rows http://polocalendar.com/

Comment: please just compare http://polocalendar.com/ to http://polocalendar.com/2018/01/27/magazine/